# Does a retail brand (e.g. Walmart or a regional coffee chain) have one Merchant ID per location, or just one for all of its locations?

Tags: credit-card, banking

Let's say I'm a big retail brand like Walmart or a small local chain of coffee shops, and I accept credit card payments.

Through my acquiring bank (or an acquiring bank by way of my MSP like Square or Toast), I have a [Merchant ID](https://www.tidalcommerce.com/learn/merchant-id-number) for accepting card transactions.

Do I have one Merchant ID for all my stores, a separate Merchant ID for each location, or something else?

What do Merchant IDs map to on a one-to-one basis? I.e. an intuitive understanding like "I have one MID for every individual retail location that accepts credit cards."

Are there nuances here? E.g., a franchise model has separate Merchant IDs for different franchise owners?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no rules on the matter and different companies operate in different ways. It can be per location, per business entity, broken down based on some internal organizational boundaries, or you can have multiple different merchant ids coded even within the same location - the POS for the grocery department will have a different merchant id than the jewellery boutique, or the cafe at the entrance.